# QR Code for Event Participant

Tags: civievent

I am thinking of creating an extension to integrate QR code for Event Participant

Do we any extension for QR code integrated already?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is an extension that adds QR code in participant email. But it updates the status when generated for participant.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin

Thanks

Pradeep